# Sphinx4 exception from SaxLoader

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to implement Speech Recognizance in Java. I have been following the tutorial and I added required jar files and libraries to the code but it is not working. It shows the error. Following is my code

```
package demo.sphinx.helloworld;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertyException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;


/**
 * A simple HelloWorld demo showing a simple speech application 
 * built using Sphinx-4. This application uses the Sphinx-4 endpointer,
 * which automatically segments incoming audio into utterances and silences.
 */
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * Main method for running the HelloWorld demo.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url;
            if (args.length > 0) {
                url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
            } else {
                url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
            }

            System.out.println("Loading...");

            ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);

        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");


            /* allocate the resource necessary for the recognizer */
            recognizer.allocate();

            /* the microphone will keep recording until the program exits */
        if (microphone.startRecording()) {

        System.out.println
            ("Say: (Good morning | Hello) " +
                     "( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | Philip | Rita | Will )");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println
            ("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

                    /*
                     * This method will return when the end of speech
                     * is reached. Note that the endpointer will determine
                     * the end of speech.
                     */ 
            Result result = recognizer.recognize();

            if (result != null) {
            String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
            System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + "\n");
            } else {
            System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
            }
        }
        } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
        recognizer.deallocate();
        System.exit(1);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem when loading HelloWorld: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PropertyException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem configuring HelloWorld: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem creating HelloWorld: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get error message like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.SaxLoader.load(SaxLoader.java:64)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.loader(ConfigurationManager.java:369)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.<init>(ConfigurationManager.java:115)
at demo.sphinx.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:48)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: assuming that you did not give any argument. is the file `helloworld.config.xml` exists in the same folder as `HelloWorld` class location?

Comment: proper tutorial to follow is here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4